# Color of gridview cells, several condition

Tags: yii2

How to change color of cell like this

```
if($data['type'] == 'London' or $data['type'] == 'Manchester' and $data['from_sale']){
            return ['style' => 'background-color:#BCC6F0;'];
        }
```

If in row 'type' value is London or Manchester then change color of cell in row 'from_sell'. Color must changed only in two cells in row  'from_sell'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `contentOptions`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
    'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return ['style' => 'background-color:' 
            . ($model->type == 'London' ? 'red' : 'blue')];
    },
],
```

Comment: I add this `'value' => 'total',
                'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return ['style' => 'background-color:'
                        . ($model->type == 'London' ? 'red' : 'blue')];
                },` Always cells in column total are blue

Comment: Propably because your `$model->type` is not `London`.

Comment: Not all the attributes for the anonymous function are required so you can simplify it to `function ($model) {`

Comment: http://joxi.ru/krD0ewji7j4Zrp `'value' => 'total',
                'contentOptions' => function ($model) {
                    return ['style' => 'background-color:'
                        . ($model->type == 'eu_dhl' ? 'red' : 'blue')];
                },`

Comment: I add this `'contentOptions' => function ($data) {
                    if ($data['type'] == 'London') {
                        $class = 'danger';
                    }
                    return ['class' => $class];
                },` All work, but how change for concrete color, not just danger or warning?

Comment: Don't use `class`, use `style` and as value `background-color: #color`

Answer (score 0):

Since Yii uses Bootstrap you are better of using a Bootstrap class rather than style as below:

```
            'contentOptions' => function($model) {
                  if ($model->taskduedt < date("Y-m-d")) {
                      return ['class' => 'table-danger',];
                  } elseif ($model->taskduedt == date("Y-m-d")) {
                      return ['class' => 'table-warning',];
                  }
                    else return ['class' => '',];
            },
```